# Fullcalendar prevent eventDidMount triggers constanty while dragging

Tags: fullcalendar, tippyjs

I have a Tippy.js integrated into a FullCalendar.js calendar.
While dragging an event inside the calendar, the tooltips get crazy, losing reference to the event that triggered it.

I think the issue is that I'm creating the Tippy (tooltip) instance inside the `eventDidMount` hook, and this being call while dragging every time the dragged event is snaped to a calendar cell, and that is why it triggers lots of tooltips in the process.

Fullcalendar has a hook for `eventDragStart(eventInfo)` but I don't know how to get to the attached tippy instance to hide it. Or should I prevent creating a tooltip at all while dragging instead?

```
 //Other FullCalendar Initialization
 ...
 eventDidMount: function(info) {
     tippy(info.el, {
        interactive: true, 
        delay: 300,
        theme: 'light-border',
        maxWidth: 400,
        allowHTML: true,
        appendTo: document.getElementById('mainContent'),   
        content(reference) {
            //Tooltip content
            return tempRendered;
        },
      });                                     
 }
 eventDragStart(info){
   //I SUPPOSE HERE I SHOULD DO SOMETHING TO HIDE THE TIPPY TOOLTIP
 }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally found the way to fix this in FullCalendar, not in Tippy.

I set an `_isDragging` property on the event inside the eventDragStart hook:

```
    eventDragStart: function(info) {                            
        calendarInstance.getEventById(info.event.id).setExtendedProp( "_isDragging", true );

    },
```

That way, I can check this flag inside the `eventDidMount` hook and prevent the creation of the Tippy tooltip.

```
 eventDidMount: function(info) {  
                               
       const isDragging = 
calendarInstance.getEventById(info.event.id).extendedProps._isDragging;
       if (isDragging != null && isDragging) {
           return;
       }
    
       ...
        // Tippy Init
    },
```

**IMPORTANT:**
I'm setting the _isDragging property directly to the event instance inside the Calendar instance, because of the info.event args these hooks receive don't have the properties created on the fly.  Or at least I didn't find a way to make it work.